# Can't deploy Ad Hoc Release in XE8

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

I can’t seem to deploy iOS Ad Hoc releases at all now with XE8. Is there something I've done wrong? Already emailed Emba support but seeking maybe a faster response here.

For any old or new applications:

```
1) Selecting -> Release Build Configuration  
2) Selecting -> IOS Device 64-bit ( or 32 ) -> Target Ad Hoc
3) Project -> Options -> Provisioning -> Attempt to select from drop downs but only ‘Auto’ available
4) Compile + Build + Deploy = fails : "[Error Error] Missing provisioning information. Distribution certificate has not been specified for the "Adhoc" platform configuration."
```

Well, unlike before in Xe7 where I could enter manually to specify, I no longer can now..... I have double checked and the cert's and provisoning profiles are installed in Xcode and KeyChain as they should be on my mac.

Also regarding ‘3)’, when selecting ‘Debug’ instead of ‘Ad Hoc’ from the provisioning selection, then all appears as should be and I can see all of my installed provisioning profiles followed by their corresponding Certificates within my KeyChain.

Anyone encounter this or have any suggestions on how to deploy Ad Hoc Release?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue - http://community.embarcadero.com/index.php/answers/xe8-cannot-submit-to-app-store

Answer (score 1):

Some things to try.  These have helped me get my app onto the device.:

Try deleting all your provisioning profiles off the Mac.

Ensure your device is referenced correctly in the Apple developer site, download the app provisioning profile and re-install it.

Try deleting your apps provisioning profiles off the iPhone (right click the device in the XCode device manager, select Show Provisioning Profiles)

Ensure you have the Apple App id "com.mydomain.myapp" in the appropriate cfBundleIdentifierfield in your apps project "version info".

Try deleting any .plist files from your project sub directories.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem -- the fix was to delete the AndroidManifest.Template file from my project directory. I had previously edited this file to work around an issue with XE7, and the changes are apparently not compatible with XE8. Deleting the file causes XE8 to use its default AndroidManifest template file, which then allowed me to deploy my app again.

Answer (score -1):

In Delphi XE8 there is a specific folder you need to place the provisioning files in your MAC machine.

**/Users/{your user}/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/**

*Note. Library is hidden so you need to use the Go To Folder command to get in to this folder.*

Comment: When you install provisioning profiles via Xcode ( Double-Click in Finder after download ) then they automatically get placed into that folder. All my provisioning profiles are already there so unfortunately this does not solve my problem.

Comment: This doesn't solve for me either.  The issue is not that it cannot find the profile, it finds that okay, but just cannot see the distribution certificate reference by the profile.

Comment: You must supply your distribution certificate with the proper key provided by the key chain app. Then download your distribution certificate and install it in the key chain.